# One-to-one continuous mapping preserve openness?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a proof, and I see the following steps.

> Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open, and $g:U\to\mathbb R^n$ be one-to-one continuously differentiable where $det g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in U$. Then $g(U)$ is open.

No further explanation about this is given. I *guess* the reason is "one-to-one continuous mapping preserve openness". But I don't know how to show this, and I am not even sure if this is the right direction. Please help me clarify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the inverse function theorem?

First suppose $det (dg(p))\neq0$ for all $p\in U$ and $dg$ is also continuous. Thus, by the inverse function theorem, there exists open sets  $p\in U_p\subset U$ and $g(p)\in V_p\subset R^n$ such that $g:U_p\to V_p$ is a diffeomorphism. Finally note that $g(U)=\bigcup_{p\in U} V_p$.

Answer (score 4):

This is true by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

It is not true in general that one-to-one continuous mappings preserve openness: a simple counterexample is provided by the inclusion $[0,1]\hookrightarrow\mathbb R$. (Here the domain is not an open subset of an Euclidean space, so the conditions of the theorem mentioned above do not apply.)

Comment: you probably want to edit your answer a bit since "It is not true that one-to-one continuous mappings preserve openness" is likely not what you want to say

Comment: I searched about this theorem, and seems that its proof is very complicated. I just added the extra condition $detg'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U$, together with the differntiability, is there a simpler way to show that $g(U)$ is open?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ: A google search yields [this proof](https://gist.github.com/pervognsen/11251717) by (?) Per Vognsen, who also appears to be a MSE user.

Comment: @user190080: I'm not sure I see what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Comment: the theorem which you're referring to says exactly that: openness is preserved by an injective continuous map under the assumptions of the OP's question